# Can't set static variable

Tags: c

```
uint64 gameVarsAddress; 
switch(version) { 
case 100: 
  gameVarsAddress = 0x44500000; 
  break; 
case 105: 
  gameVarsAddress = 0x4730000; 
  break; 
} 
static struct _gameVars *gameVars = (struct _gameVars *)(void*)gameVarsAddress;
```

**when I use compile it give me error:**
`error: initializer element is not constant | 46`

Comment: `#define gameVarsAddress 0x44500000u` The declaration of `uint64 gameVarsAddress;` makes `gameVarsAddress` mutable. What hardware are you working with?

Comment: The value used to initialize static variables is determined at compilation time. So you can probably make it compile by removing the first line and replacing it with its value in the second line. But how do you know that address will have available memory? It this bare metal code?

Comment: I don't want use #define because I want to make address selector
```
uint64 gameVarsAddress;
switch(version) {
case 100:
gameVarsAddress = 0x44500000;
break;
case 105:
gameVarsAddress = 0x4730000;
break;
}
static struct _gameVars *gameVars = (struct _gameVars*)(void*)gameVarsAddress;
```

Comment: You don't need both of those casts

Comment: Note that casting an absolute address to a pointer without including `volatile` is very likely a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Variables with static storage duration, i.e. those declared either at file scope or with the keyword `static`, can only be initialized with a *constant expression*.  The value of a variable, even if `const`, is not a constant expression.

If you use a macro for the value then you can do this.  If you don't want `gameVarsAddress` to be a macro you can still use one to initialize both `gameVarsAddress` and `gameVars`:

```
#define GAME_VARS_ADDRESS_DEFAULT 0x44500000
uint64 gameVarsAddress = GAME_VARS_ADDRESS_DEFAULT;
static struct _gameVars *gameVars = 
    (struct _gameVars*)(void*)GAME_VARS_ADDRESS_DEFAULT;
```

If on the other hand you want to set the value of `gameVars` at runtime, you'll need to first initialize it to NULL then set the value later:

```
static struct _gameVars *gameVars = NULL;
if (!gameVars) {
    // set gameVarsAddress 
    gameVars = (struct _gameVars*)(void*)gameVarsAddress;
}
```

Comment: Minor: `gameVars = (void*)gameVarsAddress;` would be sufficient.